SQL UPDATE/INSERT with UnityJDBC - MultiSource Plugin
On SQuirrelSQL client I have installed the plugin "*UnityJDBC - MultiSource Plugin" that allow multiple sources.
I need to an INSERT or UPDATE on a PostgreSQL, but i alway get an error, even if postgresql source is the only involved.

ExampleExceptionFormatter: exception message was:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "temp_Field" of
relation "temp_Table" does not exist   Position: 30

In the plugin, besides postgresSQL tables I've also added a source with an Access db (local mdb file)
AT the moment I can

execute SELECT queries with fields from both sources.
execute INSERT queries writing in the access database

*UnityJDBC - MultiSource Plugin is trial and limited to 99 entries

The issue was not related to the plugin but to SQL code for PostgreSQL; there were caps on table and column names.
Although names in the SQL were correct, it seems that it is a problem.

In PostgreSQL, names of identifiers are always folded to lowercase
unless you surround the identifier name with double quotes.

